# Ryan Fait custom form elements plugin. Multiple CSS classes issues

Tags: jquery, css, input, custom-controls

I'm using Ryan Fait's Custom form elements plugin http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/ for checkboxes and radio buttons styling.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="" class="styled" id="check" />
<label for="check">Check me!</label>
```

Plugin finds input with `.styled` class, hides it and adds a `<span>` element instead.
This works fine until I add another CSS class to the input:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="" class="styled required" id="check" />
<label for="check">Check me!</label>
```

In this case default input disappears but as I understand after this `<span>` element is not added and I only see the label. Looks like the plugin just can't find element with '.styled' class.

It' doesn't matter what class I add to the input before or after `.styled` class, so I\m sure it's not a CSS issue.

Does anybody have the same issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the plugin.

If you are using Ryan Fait's Custom form elements and there is a need to add more classes to `input` element, the plugin must be edited.

What I did to fix this behavior is a next little change. I replaced this statement

```
inputs[a].className == "styled"
```

with this one

```
($(inputs[a]).hasClass("styled"))
```

in all cases. After this styling started working correctly.